# Hibernate - ID from table inside another entity

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to map an entity on Hibernate, that has 3 primary keys. One of them is inside another entity (and is the pk of that entity also).

When I'm trying to do an inner join using Criteria, if the C class is inside de pk class (or has the @ID anotation) I get an error, but when I remove it from the PK class, everything works just fine.

I think I have a problem with my mapping. Here are the classes:

A class:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class A implements Serializable {        
    @EmbeddedId @Id
    private BPK pk;
    ... ... 
}
```

My PK class:

```
@Embeddable
public class BPK implements Serializable {    
    @Column(name = "year")
    private Integer year;

    @Column
    private C c;
    ... ... 
}
```

The class which contains the last pk:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class C {

    @Id @Column
    private Integer code;

    @Column
    private String name;
    ... ... 
}
```

Comment: What error do you get when you leave `C` as part of `BPK` and issue the join query?

Comment: The HQL generated doesn't have the inner join in it. I tried with the OneToOne JoinColumn annotations (on C inside the PK class) and only works if I remove the ID from that object.